# Pushing unindexed numeric keys to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you push unindexed numeric keys defined by a variable into an array with Javascript?

```
var arr = [{
    "1" : {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "job": "Stackoverflow"
    }
}]
```

I would like to append this array:

```
"200" : {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "job": "Stackoverflow"
}
```

without having to deal with 2-199 null objects

Comment: You need to be more specific. What you want to push and how end result should look like?

Comment: What are "unindexed numeric keys"? What array do you want to push them into?

Comment: I will edit my question :)

Comment: Why are you putting an object in an array and then put another array with an object in that object? It makes no sense to put a single object in an array. Why don't you put that object directly into that array? I guess you want something like `arr.push({object with properties});`

Comment: @GuyT doesnt have to be an object, just wondering how I could append it without dealing with 199 null objects between if I add a 200 key right after the first one

Comment: @NabilGhulam Could you explain me why you think you will have 199 null objects if you just push one object? What is the scenario you are facing? I think you the 'id' is the userid, am I correct? You could use somehting like this: `arr.push({200:{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","job":"Stackoverflow"}});`

Comment: Because atm I am pushing them like this: var arr[$scope.catId] = data; And then I get everything between aswell @GuyT

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your question. When you create an index in an array with lets say 200 your array length will grow to 201. To solve this I would use an object instead of an array: `var obj = {}; obj[200] = {"name":"Guy","age":24};`. You can access the data by using `obj[200](the id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting the second element per json, right? So you can simply do the following:

```
obj = JSON.parse(your_json);
arr.push(obj[200])
```

If you get more Objects or if you don't know the index of your element, use the Object.keys() method and iterate over all of them. More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure about your requirement. But I hope this might help

```
function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
    return a;
}

var arr = {
    "1" : {
        "firstname": "John1",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "job": "Stackoverflow"
    }
}

var b = {
"200" : {
    "firstname": "John2",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "job": "Stackoverflow"
}
};

console.log(extend(arr, b));
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phebbsu9/)